# Sybase - Subquery in FROM clause

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I'm using Sybase ASE 12.5.0.3 and I'm unable to do subqueries like:

```
select * from (select '1' union select '2' ) X
```

I've been looking around and as far as I know it should be possible after Sybase ASE 12, am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible with this version???

**Edit** - Even after changing the query to:

```
select * from (select '1' as col1 union select '2' as col1 ) X
```

So even giving alias to the columns, it fails anyways...

Answer (score 6):

Without seeing an error message, it appears that you need to give column aliases in your sub-query:

```
select * 
from 
(
    select '1' as yournewCol 
    union 
    select '2' as yournewCol
) X
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your columns name.  Try this:

Comment: I am unable to insert the code sample.  Just put "as col" after '1'.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase ASE does not support subqueries in the FROM clause:

> Subqueries can be nested inside the where or having clause of an outer select, insert, update, or delete statement, inside another subquery, or in a select list. Alternatively, you can write many statements that contain subqueries as joins; Adaptive Server processes such statements as joins.

Comment: I don't think the above quote is quite correct.   Sybase refers to the OP syntax as "SQL-Derived Tables" which is basically what we'd consider as a subquery in a FROM clause - supported as early as 12.5.1. I just tried the OP's fixed version in ASE 15.7 and it worked fine (the one without column names did not work).    http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug198.htm